# Retrieve Program Execution Time in Perf Sampling Mode

Tags: linux, trace, sampling, perf, utilization

I am using `Perf` to detect the *number* and *locations* of DRAM accesses in a workload. For locations, I need to trace in **sampling mode**. Therefore, I trace in sampling mode, and in order to get the **total** number of accesses, I **multiply** the number of access events by the sampling period (i.e., the *number* of instructions *between* each sample) .

I also need the **total time** the application is **on the CPU**. In other words, I need a value similar to what is reported by `top`. Because I need to know the *idle* period (during which the application is also **on** the CPU) between each DRAM access in this single application. This is not reported in sampling mode and I can not use both modes (i.e., both `perf record` and `perf stat`) at the same time. Is there any mechanism to achieve this?

Comment: Record a separate event like `task-clock`, and look at the total for it maybe?  I don't think you'll get good results extrapolating time from L3 miss samples.  But if you actually want to know the times between L3-miss events, I think each event should be timestamped.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. I want only the DRAM idle time during which the process is **on** the processor. In other words, the time period when the processor is *Idle* or is running some *other process* is not intended. I edited the question.

Comment: Ok, so that rules out just using timestamps on the existing events I guess?  `task-clock` only counts when a thread of a task is active on a core.

Comment: Sorry, @PeterCordes. You mean that I should sample two events (`L3-misses` and `task-clock`), simultaneously? If `task-clock` accounts for the time of a process on the processor, then it is OK. Then I should multiply the number of samples by the period (i.e., the number of events between successive samples), right?

Comment: I'm not sure how easily you can get `perf report` to show you what you want to know;  what you really want is `perf stat -e task-clock` alongside your samples from `perf record` for L3-misses.  But yes, the kernel does track when it schedules / deschedules a task so the info of exactly how many CPU-nanoseconds a process has been running for is there somewhere.  It's just a matter of getting that recorded somehow.

Comment: Can I use `Ftrace` with something like `echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_stat_runtime/enable` besides `Perf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ftrace` dump is huge. It dumps logs for every process, while I only need information for my program and its threads. `Ftrace` filter can only work on `PID`s. But I need process names (a.k.a, `comm`s). So this is the best that I could do without recompiling the kernel.

I used `Systemtap` with the following script:

```
sudo stap -e 'probe scheduler.process_exit {if (execname() == "evince"){printf("%s, %lu\n", execname(), task_current()->se->sum_exec_runtime)}}'
```

`scheduler.process_exit()` is a probe point from the `Systemtap` [tapset](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/tapsets/) library, that internally hooks the `do_exit()` kernel function (I used the former because it seems more portable). `execname()` returns the process name and `task_current()` returns the task for the current context. `se` (a *schedulable entity* for the scheduler) is a field in `task_struct` (data structure associated with a process or thread in *Linux*) and `sum_exec_runtime` shows the total *physical runtime* of the schedulable entity.

So, this is what the script does:

At each process (or thread) exit, it checks if the name of the process (or thread)
is *evince*. If this is the case, the *total execution time* (in nanoseconds) of *evince* will be displayed (because we are in the context of the *evince* process before exit).

Obviously, this is not the most portable solution.